# Discrete time signals connected in series

Tags: impulse-response, homework

> Two discrete-time systems are connected in series. Their input-output difference equations are:
>
> \begin{align}
> w[k]&=0.25x[k-2]\\
> y[k]&=0.5w[k-1]+0.5w[k-2].
> \end{align}
>
> 1. Determine the overall input-output difference equation relating $y[k]$ to $x[k]$
> 2. Determine the impulse response of the overall system

Julie.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to put $w[k]$ into $y[k]$:

$$w[k]=0.25x[k-2] \Rightarrow \begin{align}w[k-1]&=0.25x[k-3]\\
 w[k-2]&=0.25x[k-4]
\end{align}$$

\begin{align}
y[k] &= 0.5w[k-1] + 0.5w[k-2]\\
&=0.5\cdot0.25x[k-3] + 0.5\cdot0.25x[k-4]\\
&= 0.125(x[k-3]+x[k-4])
\end{align}

You can directly read the impulse response from it.

Comment: okay, and then i know what the b3 and the b4 koefficients are (0.125), Okay this might be a very stupid quastion but, how do i read the impulse response from this? and Thank you

Comment: The impulse response is [0, 0, 0, 0.125, 0.125, 0, 0, 0, ....]